# subpackages can't be imported after package installed with pip

Tags: python, import, module, package, setuptools

I have a project called build-your-own-computer with a structure that looks like this:

```
build-your-own-computer
├── computer
│   ├── arithmetic
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logic
│   └── memory
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── setup.py~
├── solutions
│   ├── arithmetic
│   │   ├── half_adder.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.py~
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py~
│   ├── logic
│   │   ├── _and.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py~
│   │   ├── _not.py
│   │   ├── _or.py
│   │   └── xor.py
│   └── memory
│       └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── arithmetic
    │   └── test_half_adder.py
    ├── logic
    │   ├── test_and.py
    │   ├── test_not.py
    │   ├── test_or.py
    │   └── test_xor.py
    └── memory
```

My goal is to be able to install this project/package using pip and then to use it from anywhere on my system.  I want to import the packages/modules like this:

```
from byoc.solutions.logic import _and
from byoc.computer.arithmetic import half_adder
```

As I understand it, `build-your-own-computer` itself can be considered a package, `build-your-own-computer\computer` a subpackage, and `build-your-own-computer\computer\logic\` a sub-sub-package.  All `.py` files besides **init**'s and `setup.py` are modules.  Is this correct, and does the import scheme above correspond with this project structure?

All of the `__init__.py` files are empty.

`setup.py` contains the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='byoc',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

When I install this using pip and then try importing the submodules, I run into problems:

```
>>> from byoc.solutions.logic import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'byoc.solutions'
```

I can import `byoc` without errors.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: First thing I'd test is, do all the imports work "locally". That is, I'd set `PYTHONPATH=.` and `cd` to the directory `byoc` exists in, then test importing it, and importing submodules.

Comment: But `byoc` isn't even defined in your project structure (I don't see a dir named `byoc` and containing an `__init__.py`). How can it be importable? _As I understand it, `build-your-own-computer` itself can be considered a package_ no, `build-your-own-computer` is the directory containing your project. The packages are `computer` and `solutions`, so e.g. `from computer import logic` should work. If you want a `byoc` package, create it in your project dir and move `computer` and `logic` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-a-src-layout) the suggested layout by setuptools. Also [here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/) is a good guide.
Here is my suggestion on your layout:

```
build-your-own-computer
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   └── byoc
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── computer
│       │   ├── arithmetic
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── logic
│       │   └── memory
│       └── solutions
│           ├── arithmetic
│           │   ├── half_adder.py
│           │   └── __init__.py
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── logic
│           │   ├── _and.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py~
│           │   ├── _not.py
│           │   ├── _or.py
│           │   └── xor.py
│           └── memory
│               └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── arithmetic
    │   └── test_half_adder.py
    ├── logic
    │   ├── test_and.py
    │   ├── test_not.py
    │   ├── test_or.py
    │   └── test_xor.py
    └── memory
```

And then your `setup.py` should be:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='byoc',
    packages=find_packages('src/')
    package_dir={'': 'src/'},
)
```

This way you should then be able to import it anywhere, e.g.:

```
from byoc.solutions import logic
```